# Click through JTextArea?

Tags: java, click, jlabel, jtextarea, mouselistener

I have a class that extends JPanel. On the panel I have added an JLabel for a image and a few JTextArea (setEditable, setCursor, setOpaque, setFocusable to false) for text. This class is intended to be put in a list-fashion, top to bottom. When the user clicks on one of the JPanels some actions should happen depending on the selected item (JPanel). I have added an addMouseListener which works, but it wont register clicks if the user clicks somewhere where there is text. It work if I change the JTextArea to JLabel but the reason I used JTexArea is because I want/need wordwrap. 
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Put up some code and avoid us reading your english describing your code. It will save us all some time

Comment: As suggested below, add the mouse listener on the JTextArea as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding same mouselistener to JTextArea Also.

Comment: You just made my day. Thanks! Works!